# Disable auto fill of input tag in html?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a webpage taking a new user name & password as input. For scripting, I am using AngularJS.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <input ng-model="prc.userName" placeholder="User Name" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="nope" required autofocus />
</div>
```

This input box always gets auto-filled, I don't want it to get auto-filled.

Question reviewed prior: [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

```
// These attributes do not work
autocomplete="off"
autocomplete="false"
```

My chrome version: Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

How can I do that?

Comment: changed tag to angular js

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle or any other snippet?

Comment: bro i have a working solution,,please see my answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag?page=2&tab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a known error and it can be really annoying. for some reason `autocomplete='false'` and `autocomplete='off'` aren't working at all in chrome.

The only known method to get rid of it is to use `autocomplete='new-password'`, this will deactivate the autocomplete!

Cheers

Comment: This solution actually worked for me, thanks

Comment: *question reviewed prior*?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49376393/3840840 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/41398325/3840840

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I missed that I tried "off", "false" flags with autocomplete

Comment: No probs @pcj if you found my answer 'the answer' could you please mark my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add autocomplete="off" onto (form) element;

Add hidden (input) with autocomplete="false" as a first children element of the form.