# How to disable username autofill in Chrome for certain fields?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have simple search input which appears after auth, but chrome tries to fill it with username.

[image]

```
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="username">
<input type="search" class="form-control" id="input-search" placeholder="@lang('search.search_site')" value="{{ request()->get('search', '') }}" autocomplete="none" name="search-input">
```

Tried different things bu still it suggests username here. I think because its first input on page....

P.S.
Tried autocomplete:off,no,none

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: use autocomplete off

Comment: `Tried different things` What different things did you try?

Comment: autocomplete:off,no,none

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me a little crazy also.  Got round it like this.

```
<input type="number" id="your-id" class="form-control text-center border-success" 
placeholder="Enter desired code" />

$(function() {
        $('#your-id').attr("type","text");
});
```

HTH :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is working for me is to set `autocomplete` attribute value to `new-password`:

```
<input placeholder="placeholder text" value="" autocomplete="new-password"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> Add autocomplete="off" onto <form> element;
> Add hidden <input> with autocomplete="false" as a first children element of the form.
> ```
>
> Try this:

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="">
    <input autocomplete="false" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
```

> You can also create a couple of fields and make them hidden with
>   "display:none"

```
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="user_name"/>
```

Comment: i dont use form.

Comment: Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55866420/)